# Can gyms give you Field Research?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live close to a gym and spin it often for items. Can I spin it to give me field research quests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only 'real' Poké-Stops give these quests. You have to walk a little bit further to get these quests.